# linux freeipa client смена пароля

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ldap

Имеется сервер на free ipa. В политиках паролей установлено время жизни по 0 ( т.е. бесконечно как понял ). Но после создания пользователей и попытки авторизоваться под ними на клиентской машине - пишет Password expires please change. Чяднт?